# Combine\Merge Same Label in Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, data-visualization

I have a pie chart that shows states\countries oil data:

https://codepen.io/epicfreakdotcom/pen/bGwZgJr

As above codes my data:

> United States = 51.2 Canada = 50,2 Canada = 150

Its seems working very well with that conditon but i wish to display those values like below:

```
United States = 51,2
Canada = 200,2
```

(1st Canada + 2nd Canada value)  I just want to use all label once with total value. I did try some trick but seems doesnt working properly. I also tried to use amcharts group slicer but that plugin only works on lower values.
I want to group same name values in same instances to calculate on pie chart. I really appreciate if someone could help me out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about combining the data yourself in a custom function before putting it into the chart, that will fix your problem